# in_array em uma array com sub_arrays

Tags: php

Estou com uma dificuldade e peço a ajuda de vocês.

Tenho um valor trazido do banco por exemplo: 250

Preciso fazer um for nesse valor. Tranquilo:

```
for ($i=0; $i<250; $i++) {

}
```

Agora eu tenho um array de **rocks**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rock] => 10
            [status] => Opened
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [rock] => 25
            [status] => Opened
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [rock] => 80
            [status] => Opened
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [rock] => 15
            [status] => Opened
        )

)
```

Esse **array** traz os ids dos **registros** (**rock**) gravados no banco com seus respectivos **status**.

Meu **objetivo** é verificar se quando o laço **for** passar por cada número de 1 à 250 se existe no **array** acima um  **subArray**

```
 Array
            (
                [rock] => 15
                [status] => Opened
            )
```

cujo índice **rock** seja igual ao número da vez no laço for.

Caso seje igual, eu acrescento uma classe css no elemento a ser criado.

Tentei da forma abaixo mas a lógica não funcionou pois o objetivo é criar **buttons** de 1 à 250.

```
<?php
$rocks_count = 250;
for ($i=0;$i<$rocks_count; $i++){
    foreach($rocks as $rock) {                  
        $achou = $i+1 === $rock["rock"]
                    ? $rock
                    : null;
    }   
    echo $achou === null
        ? "<button class='btnRafle'>" . $i+1 . "</button><br>"
        : "<button class='btnRafle achou'>" . $i+1 . "</button><br>";                  
}
?>
```

Tentei também da forma abaixo mas não funcionou:

```
for ($i=0;$i<$rocks_count; $i++){
    if(in_array($i, array_column($rocks, 'rvok'))){
        echo $rocks["rock"] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Consegui!

Array $rocks:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rock] => 10
            [status] => Opened
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [rock] => 25
            [status] => Opened
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [rock] => 80
            [status] => Opened
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [rock] => 15
            [status] => Opened
        )

)
```

PHP:

```
$rocks_count = 250;

for ($i=1;$i<=$rocks_count; $i++){

    $key = array_search($i, array_column($rocks, 'rock'));

    if ($key !== false) {

        switch ($rocks[$key]["status"]) {
            case "Opened":
                $button = "<button class='btnRafle Opened'>" . $i . "</button><br>";
                break;
            case "Payed":
                $button = "<button class='btnRafle Payed'>" . $i . "</button><br>";
                break;
            default:
                $button = "<button class='btnRafle free'>" . $i . "</button><br>";
        }
        
    } else 
        $button = "<button class='btnRafle free'>" . $i . "</button><br>";
    

    echo $button;
}
```